# A common expression for spots or "stains" on clothing, or on a surface / finish

Tags: word-choice

I found the word "stains" for spots and marks on dict.cc by 
asking myself what would be the best/common English word to use to express a stain or mark on clothing, products, finishings, or at physical occurence.

EG: 
 - A darker shape on a white shirt caused by pouring wine accidentaly on it.
 - A shape of different color on a paint-finish (cars or products)

Comment: That's a "spot" or a "stain".

Comment: 'Blemish' might well cover both.

Comment: You’ve noted the background behind finding the word *stain* in a dictionary. What’s your question?

Comment: The fact is that I have never heard that word before. I have done a lot of technic, business, artwork and computer with English papers or in discussions the last 25 years. Therefore, i wanted to ask what the common expression for the examples is. Maybe I also didn't recognize it until now.

Comment: "Stain" is an incredibly common word in the US.  Just walk down the laundry products aisle of a grocery or department store: https://www.thespruce.com/top-stain-removers-for-laundry-1900909

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the "dark shape on a shirt caused by wine" example, your best bet by far would be stain. I'm having a hard time coming up with any other word that would be understandable in that context.

Stain strongly implies that the color was changed by a strongly-colored agent, usually a dye or something similar. For example, we would also use "stain" to describe treating wood to give it a darker color. "Stain" comes from the old french "desteindre", meaning "to tinge with a color different than the natural one". This would fit your "wine on the shirt" example perfectly, and similar marks caused by dye, ink, food, etc.

If we're looking at a differently-colored area of a paint job or finish, there are several words that could work:

[Flaw](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/flaw)

> A crack or breach, a gap or fissure; a defect of continuity or cohesion.

This would in general be good for your needs, but especially appropriate if there is a *defect of continuity*, i.e. most of the finish is uniform, but part of it does not share continuity with the surrounding area.

[Blotch](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/blotch)

> An uneven patch of color or discoloration ... An irregularly shaped area.

This would work well for your definition, but anecdotally I feel it's not used as often as a noun - I usually see this as the adjective "blotchy".

[Blemish](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/blemish)

> A small flaw which spoils the appearance of something, a stain, a spot.

Blemish fits your definition, but is often used in the context of skin (e.g. "...to minimize the appearance of facial blemishes or pimples, use a concealer with a dry texture...").

There are additional words that could be used when describing errors in applying a finish or paint job (see [chip](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/chip#Noun) (#2), [scratch](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/scratch#Noun), [smudge](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/smudge#Noun), [crack](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/crack#Noun), etc) depending on the specific type of flaw.